# React Native File system path for IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fetch-blob

i am using a RNFetchBlob for getting files in react-native. Code is as follows -

```
  RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(
        ('/Users/UserName/Project/documents/' + this.state.name),
        'base64',
        4095)
      .then((ifstream) => {
        ifstream.open();
        ifstream.onData((chunk) => {
          this.setState({data: chunk});
        })

        ifstream.onError((err) => {
          console.log('oops', err)
        })

        ifstream.onEnd(() => {
          this._decodeData();
        })
      });
```

This code works perfectly when running it on an emulator on my macbook, but i was wondering what the file path would be running it on my iphone? Obviously - it cant find the file when i try to do so.

I would like some sort of non-absolute path to be used but not sure how this is done with RNFetchBlob. When loading images, require('../images/image.png') works perfectly, just not this scenario

Thanks in advance -

Comment: What is the file you're trying to read, and where did it come from?

Comment: I am saving the files in the react-native project folder, the documents folder is located in the same area as index.ios.js @SoZettaSho

Comment: Ok, so `react-native-fetch-blob` is really more for giving you access to the device's local filesystem. The reason I asked is I'm trying to figure out if you are trying to use a static resource, or if it is a file you might want to download to the device first. If it's the former, fetch blob probably isn't the right tool to use

Comment: @SoZettaSho would you recommend any tools to do so?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what kind of file it is. If it's some sort of data file the easiest way would be to convert it or transfer the data to a JS/JSON format and then import it. If it's something that can be accessed from the internet, you could try the download it locally then read with fetchBlob route. Otherwise, you would have to look into how assets are handled on the native iOS side (all I know about that is that it's considerably more complicated than android)

Comment: It turns out I was partly wrong about fetchBlob, it [does have a way to handle assets](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#assetfilenamestringstring), but it looks like on iOS it just gives you access to the camera roll. The author has indicated intent to add the feature properly in the future though